# Django WSGI Script Won't load due to a Python issue

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get Django to run through mod_wsgi on Apache2.22 but I'm getting an internal 500 error.
I know there are other questions for this, but they don't have my specific error. Here is my traceback:

```
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [info] [client 128.227.11.143] mod_wsgi (pid=23071, process='partender', application='www.***.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/usr/home/***.com/zpencerq/part/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143] mod_wsgi (pid=23071): Target WSGI script '/usr/home/***.com/zpencerq/part/apache/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143] mod_wsgi (pid=23071): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/home/***.com/zpencerq/part/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]   File "/usr/home/partender.myprotosite.com/zpencerq/part/apache/django.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]     from threading import Lock
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 15, in <module>
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]     from collections import deque
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 9, in <module>
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143]     from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
[Sat Jun 16 02:17:48 2012] [error] [client 128.227.11.143] ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so: Undefined symbol "_PyUnicodeUCS4_AsDefaultEncodedString"
```

it seems to be an issue with python but I have no idea what to do with that last error in the traceback. is that a problem with the python install?
I have done the simple WSGI hello world app, and that works perfectly fine. It's an issue with makign the django call.

I used 'ldd' on mod_wsgi.so and got the following output:

```
root@blah# ldd mod_wsgi.so
mod_wsgi.so:
ldd: mod_wsgi.so: Shared object "mod_wsgi.so" not found, required by "ldd"
mod_wsgi.so: exit status 1
```

Comment: For reference, 'ldd' should be run on the mod_wsgi.so in your Apache installation. IOW, give a full path or be in the same directory. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library

Comment: I was in the same directory. I'm taking that response as mod_wsgi.so is using a Python static library rather than shared.

Comment: No such thing. It says ldd could not find a file called mod_wsgi.so in the directory you were in. If it was statically linked it would still generate output but not show dependency on libpythonX.Y.so.

Comment: you were right. apparently i did something wrong though i'm pretty sure i did pwd and was in the current directory

root@seese# ldd /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so
/usr/local/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so:
        libutil.so.7 => /lib/libutil.so.7 (0x2817d000)
        libm.so.5 => /lib/libm.so.5 (0x2818a000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x28080000)

Comment: Graham, this question has been solved. I created a new question about further issues with WSGI and Django here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092089/django-wsgi-application-segfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your mod_wsgi is compiled against one Python installation but you are trying to force it to use a different Python installation. The reason you are having a problem is because one Python installation was compiled with UCS2 support and the other UCS4.

Use 'ldd' on mod_wsgi.so to show what Python installation it is trying to use and then provide that information as part of question along with mod_wsgi configuration or WSGI script contents where you are trying to force it to use different Python installation, or incompatible virtual environment.

Comment: This specific issue was due to an incompatible version of Python vs what mod_wsgi3 was compiled for! (running 2.7.2, mod_wsgi3 was compiled for 2.7.3) thanks! i may have another question soon and will post it separately. just wanted to say thanks Graham! i see you're like the main guy to answer many of these django/wsgi questions and also found your guide somewhere!