# Django + Apache + Mod_wsgi cuasing 500 Internal Server Error (log attached)

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv

[Django WSGI Script Won't load due to a Python issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061345/django-wsgi-script-wont-load-due-to-a-python-issue)

After a day of research, still couldn't solve the issue.
Server is Online, using site in using **virtulenv**
Windows 8-64bit, python34, Wamp server apache 64bit

Inside conf:

```
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080> 
ServerAdmin admin@hotmail.com
ServerName 192.168.0.101:8080 
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/venv/testweb10/testweb10"  
</VirtualHost>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/wamp/www/venv/testweb10/testweb10/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/wamp/www/venv/Lib/site-packages"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/venv/testweb10">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

**Settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['testweb10']
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       testweb10
```

I am suspecting if python compatibility issue

User variables path:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\python.exe;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin;
```

[image]

Please Help

Comment: mod_wsgi tries to parse your wsgi.py script but fails. What is the contents of that file?

Comment: import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testweb10.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: Thanks Saex, you reminded me.

Comment: os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "testweb10.settings"

Comment: but still get the same error result

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'testweb10'\r
[Sat Apr 04 05:23:18.765772 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 1424:tid 1220] mod_wsgi (pid=1424): Target WSGI script 'C:/wamp/www/venv/testweb10/testweb10/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a reference to your virtualenv in your wsgi.py? Here is a template I use on Linux for example:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/home/mysite/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/mysite/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

This is Django 1.6 btw. Django 1.7 has some differences in the wsgi.py

For Django 1.7 the last two lines are:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: In addition to this, ensure that you use the appropriate installer to install `mod_wsgi`. In a standard system with both Python 2 & 3 installed, `pip install mod_wsgi` will execute installation for Python 2.x, whereas `pip3 install mod_wsgi` will do the same for 3.x

Comment: The pip installable mod_wsgi isn't supported under Windows. For Windows users need to use special precompiled builds unless they want to compile from source code themselves. See https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Answer (score 0):

**WSGIPythonPath** must include root of your project.

> Used to specify additional directories to search for Python modules.
>   If multiple directories are specified they should be separated by a
>   ':' if using a UNIX like system, or ';' if using Windows.

```
WSGIPythonPath = "C:/wamp/www/venv/testweb10/testweb10;C:/wamp/www/venv/Lib/site-packages"
```

Comment: using windows is kinda different

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the following seems working for Django 1.8

```
import site
```

site.addsitedir("C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages")

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/wamp/www/venv/testweb10/testweb10")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "testweb10.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But getting errors now :( 
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3788:tid 688] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.4.10 Python/3.4.3 PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations

Answer (score 0):

For guys having the same issue:

Some suggestions(also for myself):

**Version of every component is important**

1) Install Appache or Wamp server the clean way. Makesure delete its old regedit.

2) Get Mod_WSGI and following the install instructions carefully!!!

2.5) Test the Mod_WSGI if working fine without Django

3) The Final step is to install python, Django, and setup the environments and conf.

4) Test and Deploy